# script in bash that check if string "chmod" is present in a file

Tags: grep, command

i'm trying to mitigate the problem for nebula leve03. here my solution to avoid to set the setuid bit in the file writable.sh.

when I launch the .sh I have syntax error near 'done'. can you help me, please? thank you

```
for i in /home/flag03/writable.d/* ; do
   if [$(grep -c "chmod" "$i" ) ==0] then
   (ulimit -t 5;bash -x "$i") fi
   rm -f "$i"
done
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `fi` with `; fi`.

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.